# jQuery plugin or technique to partially obscure text fields?

Tags: jquery, html, input

What I'd like to do is, as unobtrusively as possible, obscure *part* of the input on a text field (as though it were a password field) but allow the rest of it to remain plaintext.

It doesn't look like the existing input "masking" plugins do anything but ensure conformance with a provided data structure.

Is there an already-existing plugin, or well-documented technique for achieving this?

Comment: What would the logic be re: which characters were redacted/visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what it is you're after, but maybe it's something like this:

```
$('#ElementID').on('keydown keyup', function() {
    var res = this.value,
        len = res.length,
        stars = len>0?len>1?len>2?'***':'**':'*':'',
        result = stars+res.substring(3);
    $("#ElementID2").val(result);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xNmCM/1/)

It's just a quick hack, but should give you some ideas?

Comment: Wow, yeah -- that's pretty much the behavior. Accepting for time being given the completeness of the example. Thanks so much -- my requirements are slightly different but this is a great start.

Answer (score 2):

How about on change, you check to find the string positioning of the character, and replace it with your obscure character? Then write the actual string to a hidden field.

Or simply replace all characters up to a certain length, and run substr on all following strings?